# How do I get the handle of another's window (browser) from my program?

Tags: winapi

WINAPI
How do I get the handle of another's window (browser) from my program?
Searching by the name of the window does not help, as the name changes.

Comment: You could, for instance, search for the name of the window class.

Comment: Depends on how this window can be identified. How should it be identified?

Comment: Use things like `EnumWindows()`, `GetWindowText()`, and `GetClassName()`.  Enumerate top-level windows until you find one that is the desired class type and contains the desired caption text.

Comment: Use Spy++ to determine properties of the window you are looking for, such as the class name or specific child windows.

Comment: It sounds like this might be an X-Y problem.  Can you give more context?
  What's the goal?  What do you know about the window you want to find?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you want to find Google Chrome window's handle, use the following code:

```
//Find the Google Chrome 
HWND hGoogleChrome = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, L"Chrome_WidgetWin_1", NULL);
```

**Chrome_WidgetWin_1** will rename the Chrome window's name regardless of **title** that changes.